# Can we use angularjs 2 in the production environment?

Tags: angular

We are planning to use angularjs 2 in our production environment application.But couldn't find any news related to final release of AngularJS 2. Any suggestions?

Comment: why, it was released in may and is currently in version 2.1.0 as of October 12th, 2016 https://angular.io/news.html

Comment: Seriously? You typed "Angular final release" in Google, and couldn't find any result saying that it's been released for 2 months now?

Comment: @JBNizet I searched "AngularJS final release" and didn't see any useful information.

Answer (score 1):

Angular 2.0.0 released 2016-09-14 https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-proprioception-reinforcement-2016-09-14